# Книги по JQuery

Tags: jquery, книги

Где можно найти книги по JQuery ( *Не для начинающих* )?

Comment: единственная "книга" не для начинающих: [http://docs.jquery.com/](http://docs.jquery.com/), канеш ещё можно нагуглить всякие Best Practice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно найти [тут](http://progbook.net/javascript/3829-jquery-podrobnoe-rukovodstvo-po-prodvinutomu-javascript.html) и еще [тут](http://knigi.tr200.ru/f.php?f=jquery+pdf&p=0)(очень много книг на русском и английском языках), и еще есть на этом [сайте](http://www.kodges.ru/139386-pro-jquery.html). На торрентах, таких как [www.thepiratebay.se](http://www.thepiratebay.se) есть целые подшивки книг по jQuery в PDF. Пример - [43 книги по jQuery](http://thepiratebay.se/torrent/7293193/jQuery_Book_Pack_(43_Books)__BBS_)!

Comment: спс =) щас почитаю